# How to change settings for auto generated resources SAM AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I'm implemented SAM template with `AWS::Serverless::Api`:

```
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: ${AppName}-${ServiceName}
      StageName: !Ref Stage
    ...
```

AWS Developers guide says:

> "When an AWS::Serverless::Api is specified, AWS Serverless Application
> Model (AWS SAM) always generates an AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi base AWS
> CloudFormation resource. In addition, it also always generates an
> AWS::ApiGateway::Stage and an AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment resource."

So, my question is how can I change within SAM template autogenerated resources settings? For example, I want to change `LoggingLevel` for the `ApiGateway.Stage`.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `methodSettings`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html#sam-api-methodsettings

Example:

```
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
       StageName: mine
       MethodSettings:
        - HttpMethod: ...
          ResourcePath: ...
          LoggingLevel: ERROR
          ...
```